# Sencha Extjs 6.2 : Edit object values in cell grid

Tags: extjs, grid, editor, cell

I have a grid and in the last two columns (Chourly and Cdaily), each cell contains an object.
Example of data :

```
{
    data: [{
        Date: "2018/01/11 21:00:00",
        Ahourly: "1",
        Chourly: {
            val: 2,
            status: "Low",
            color: "#ffff00"
        }
    }, ...
    success: true
}
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2bs0&view/editor), see Chourly and Cdaily columns.

I need to edit data of this object and display the new values.
I tried to use beforeedit end validateedit but for now no success !

Any help ?

Thanks,

mpe

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to adjust your data model in the store.
Use "mapping" to accommodate all the fields in object field into individual fields, 
like that:

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields: [
            'Date',
            'Ahourly',
            {name:'ChourlyVal',mapping:'Chourly.val'},
            {name:'ChourlyColor',mapping:'Chourly.color'},
            {name:'ChourlyStatus',mapping:'Chourly.status'},
            {name:'CdailyVal' ,mapping:'Cdaily.val'},
            {name:'CdailyColor' ,mapping:'Cdaily.color'},
            {name:'CdailyStatus' ,mapping:'Cdaily.status'}
            ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data1.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

And than, adjust the column and the renderer to use the mapped fields:

```
 {
            text: 'Chourly',
            dataIndex: 'ChourlyVal',
            flex: 1,
            renderer: function (a, meta, record) {
                console.log(record);
                meta.tdStyle = "background-color:" + record.data.ChourlyColor + ";";
                var cellText = a + " " + record.data.ChourlyStatus;
                return cellText;
            },
            editor: 'textfield'
        }
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I think its the good way.
Then I think I have to use the serialize function to put the object back together with the modified value(s) to send back to the server like this :

```
fields: ['Date', {
                name: 'Chourly',
                serialize: function (val, rec) {
                    return {
                        'val': rec.get('val'),
                        'status': rec.get('status'),
                        'color': rec.get('color')
                    };
                }
            }, {
                name: 'val',
                mapping: 'Chourly.val',
                persist: false //Do not write back to server
            }, {
                name: 'status',
                mapping: 'Chourly.status',
                persist: false

            }, {
                name: 'color',
                mapping: 'Chourly.color',
                persist: false

            }, 
            ...
        ]...
```

Now I have to do that dynamically because I don't know in advance which data the user will consult (Chourly, Dhourly, Ehourly ....). Any idea to modify the model on the load callback ?